# Analysing probability

Tags: probability-theory

Two gamblers have an argument. The first one claims that if a fair coin is tossed
repeatedly, getting two consecutive heads is very unlikely. The second, naturally, is denying this.They decide to settle this by an actual trial; if within $n$ coin tosses, no two consecutive heads turn up, the first gambler wins.

(a) What value of $n$ should the second gambler insist on to have more than a $50\%$
chance of winning?

(b) In general, let $P(n)$ denote the probability that two consecutive heads show up within $n$ trials. Write a recurrence relation for $P(n)$.

(c) Implicit in the second gambler’s stand is the claim that for all sufficiently large $n$, there is a good chance of getting two consecutive heads in $n$ trials; i.e. $P(n) > 1/2$.In the first part of this question, one such $n$ has been demonstrated. What happens for larger values of $n$? Is it true that $P(n)$ only increases with $n$? Justify your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... If within n coin tosses, no two consecutive heads turn up, the first gambler wins.
>
> (a) What value of n should the second gambler insist on to have more than a 50% chance of winning? [Two consecutive heads means 2nd gambler wins.]

You need at least 5 coin flips to get a greater than 50% chance of a specific outcome.

HH, TT, HT, TH = 25% chance of two heads; one way for #2 to win, three ways for #2 to lose.

A third toss gives you:

HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT

```
In binary:
0 – 000
1 – 001
2 – 010
3 – 011
4 – 100
5 – 101
6 – 110
7 – 111
```

- In the first, second and fifth examples #2 wins.
- The other 5 ways #2 loses. 3 / 8 = 37.5%.

A fourth toss gives you:

HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, HTHH, HTHT, HTTH, HTTT

THHH, THHT, THTH, THTT, TTHH, TTHT, TTTH, TTTT

```
In binary:
0 – 0000
1 – 0001
2 – 0010
3 – 0011
4 – 0100
5 – 0101
6 – 0110
7 – 0111
8 – 1000
9 – 1001
A – 1010
B – 1011
C – 1100
D – 1101
E – 1110
F – 1111
```

- Eight ways to win, eight ways to lose, 50/50.

A fifth toss gives you:

HHHHH, HHHHT, HHHTH, HHHTT, HHTHH, HHTHT, HHTTH, HHTTT

HTHHH, HTHHT, HTHTH, HTHTT, HTTHH, HTTHT, THTTH, HTTTT

THHHH, THHHT, THHTH, THHTT, THTHH, THTHT, THTTH, THTTT

TTHHH, TTHHT, TTHTH, TTHTT, TTTHH, TTTHT, TTTTH, TTTTT

```
In binary:
 0 – 00000
 1 – 00001
 2 – 00010
 3 – 00011
 4 – 00100
 5 – 00101
 6 – 00110
 7 – 00111
 8 – 01000
 9 – 01001
 A – 01010
 B – 01011
 C – 01100
 D – 01101
 E – 01110
 F – 01111
10 – 10000
11 – 10001
12 – 10010
13 – 10011
14 – 10100
15 – 10101
16 – 10110
17 – 10111
18 – 11000
19 – 11001
1A – 11010
1B – 11011
1C – 11100
1D – 11101
1E – 11110
1F – 11111
```

- With 5 tosses there's 19 chances out of 32 to win, 19 / 32 = 59.375%.
- With 6 tosses there's 42 chances out of 64 to win, 42 / 64 = 65.625%.

> (b) In general, let P(n) denote the probability that two consecutive heads show up within n trials. Write a recurrence relation for P(n).

See "[Which number will follow](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081129103058AAM6TBr)" for an analysis of this recursive function.

[image: Algorithm]

> (c) Implicit in the second gambler’s stand is the claim that for all sufficiently large n, there is a good chance of getting two consecutive heads in n trials; i.e. P(n)>1/2. In the first part of this question, once such n has been demonstrated. What happens for larger values of n? Is it true that P(n) only increases with n? Justify your answer.

More flips increase #2's success rate, though it is possible to get two heads with two flips. That's clearly demonstrated above.

---

More complicated analyses are:

[coin tossed until two consecutive heads or tails appear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112726/coin-tossed-until-two-consecutive-heads-or-tails-appear)

[Flip a fair coin until three consecutive heads or tails appear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208457/flip-a-fair-coin-until-three-consecutive-heads-or-tails-appear)

Use [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) to [solve for a greater number of consecutive results](https://probabilitytopics.wordpress.com/2017/12/15/first-step-analysis-and-fundamental-matrix/).

Answer (score 0):

I think an intuitive way to approach this question is to first compute small cases by listing all outcomes.

Firstly, clearly $P(0) = P(1) = 0$ since we don't even have two trials.

Now to find $P(2)$ we list all outcomes:
$$HH \\ TH \\ HT \\ TT$$
Clearly
$$P(2)
= \frac{\#(\text{outcomes with }HH\text{ in }2\text{ trials})}{\#(\text{all outcomes in }2\text{ trials})}
= \frac{1}{2^2}$$
Now to find $P(3)$ we again list all outcomes:
$$\bbox[pink]{HHH \\ THH} \\ \bbox[lightskyblue]{HTH \\ TTH}$$
$$\bbox[yellow]{HHT \\ THT \\ HTT \\ TTT}$$
Note that we list all outcomes by copying all outcomes in the previous stage and then appending $H$ to the end followed by doing the same with $T$ instead of $H$.
Now
$$\begin{align*}
\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials})
&= \bbox[pink]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }HH)} \\
&+ \bbox[lightskyblue]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }TH)} \\
&+ \bbox[yellow]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }T)}
\end{align*}$$
Observe
$$\bbox[pink]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }HH)}
= 2^1 $$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\bbox[lightskyblue]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }TH)}
&= \#(\text{outcomes with }HH\text{ in }1\text{ trials}) \\
&= \#(\text{all outcomes in }1\text{ trials}) \cdot P(1) \\
&= 2^1 \cdot 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\bbox[yellow]{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials ending with }T)}
&= \#(\text{outcomes with }HH\text{ in }2\text{ trials}) \\
&= \#(\text{all outcomes in }2\text{ trials}) \cdot P(2) \\
&= 2^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$
So
$$P(3)
= \frac{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }3\text{ trials})}{\#(\text{all outcomes in }2\text{ trials})}
= \frac{3}{8}$$

Hence in general, we have
$$\begin{align*}
P(n)
&= \frac{\#(\text{outcomes containing }HH\text{ in }n\text{ trials})}{\#(\text{all outcomes in }2\text{ trials})} \\
&= \frac{2^{n - 1} P(n - 1) + 2^{n - 2} P(n - 2) + 2^{n - 2}}{2^n} \\
&= \frac{P(n - 1)}{2} + \frac{P(n - 2)}{4} + \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}$$
which is the recurrence relation we want. I will leave it to you to check it works for $P(4)$ and finish the rest of the question.